# Displaying specific version of geodatabase on AxImapControl using ArcObjects in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, versioning

I am working on a sample ArcGIS Engine project which tries to map two versions difference on an AxImapControl

i created two mapcontrol which first one loads the MXD file and for  second one i make a deep cloning copy of map object using IObjectCopy interface and then change the version of copied object and the load the map in mapcontrol.

but when i load map to second mapcontrol, two mapcontrols are showing the target version which i want to display on second map.

deep cloning in second map's parent form constructor

```
   IObjectCopy esriObjectCopy = new ObjectCopyClass();

        System.Object copyTarget = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap;

        esriObjectCopy.Overwrite(pMap, ref copyTarget);
```

change version after deep cloning

```
 ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IBasicMap basicMap = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IBasicMap;
        IChangeDatabaseVersion oIChangeDatabaseVersion = new ChangeDatabaseVersionClass();
        ISet set = oIChangeDatabaseVersion.Execute(_ParentVersion, _ChildVersion, basicMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved

pMap is Input arg MainMap and 
axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap is Input arg  ChildMap

```
    IObjectCopy esriObjectCopy = new ObjectCopyClass();
    System.Object copyTarget = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap;
    System.Object copySource = pMap;
    esriObjectCopy.Overwrite(copySource , ref copyTarget);
    IBasicMap basicMap = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap as IBasicMap;
    IChangeDatabaseVersion oIChangeDatabaseVersion = new ChangeDatabaseVersionClass();
   oIChangeDatabaseVersion.Execute(_ParentVersion, _ChildVersion, basicMap);
   esriObjectCopy.Overwrite(copySource , pMap);
```